# This try and catch(Exception e) is only catching the exception

Tags: java, exception

Main Class:

```
public class Table extends java.applet.Applet implements Runnable
{
     public void init()
     {
         try
         {
             Balla.addBall();
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
         }
     }
}
```

Method:

```
 public class Balla
 {
    public static int balls=0;
    public static void addBall()throws IOException
    {
    Random generator = new Random();
    Ball b = new Ball(100,100,8,Color.blue,generator.nextInt(4)+1,generator.nextInt(4)+1);
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\temp_Jon\\BallData.ballz",true);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw,true);
        pw.print(b.getX()+" "+b.getY()+" "+b.getRadius()+" "+b.color+" "+b.speedX+" "+b.speedY+"\n");
        System.out.println("qqq");
        pw.close();
        fw.close();
    balls++;
    }
 }
```

It never actually does what I want it to do and I used the try and catch in the first place because I could not apply throws IOException to the init method.

Comment: Please tag with the programming language you're using, instead of useless random keywords like "file" and "throws".

Comment: "It never actually does what I want it to do" - and what exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: This is java and I would like it to write/create the file in which I have selected.

Comment: It is not writing to the file.

Comment: Or in other words it is not calling the method addBall()

Comment: Try adding `e.printStackTrace();` in your catch block and you should be able to see where the error is more easily.

Comment: Which `Exception` you are getting?

Comment: I need to check it hold on.

Comment: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied

Comment: Oh it's applet,Sandboxing problem because applets cannot read or write files on the file system.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to I guess get around this?

Comment: @JWPM77 See my answer. I covered it for you.

Comment: [Try This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406871/is-it-possible-to-read-write-a-file-from-an-applet)

Answer (score 0):

> Or in other words it is not calling the method addBall()

I do not see where you have instantiated `Balla`. Are you getting a `NullPointerException` ?

Also, your `Exception` block is empty. Add an `e.printStackTrace()` there and post the stack trace. That'll give u a clue as to what is going wrong.

This seems like a sandboxed applet and hence cannot write to a file. Quoting from the docs:

> They cannot access client resources such as the local filesystem,
>   executable files, system clipboard, and printers.

Sources:
1. [What Applets Can and Cannot Do](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html)
2. [How can an applet Read/Write files on the local file-system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102217/how-can-an-applet-read-write-files-on-the-local-file-system)

Comment: Balla is static and doesn't need an object

Comment: @JWPM77 addBall is static Balla need to be class where this method is declared.

Comment: @TAsk I agree with u!

Comment: That is what I meant but yes I have it in the class Balla let me fix that on the question.